# Spotfire: Using Multiple Markings in a Data Function Without Needing Something Marked in Each

Tags: output, filtering, ironpython, spotfire

In Spotfire I have a dashboard that uses both filtering (only one filtering scheme) and multiple markings to show the resulting data in a table.

I have created a data function which takes a column and outputs the data in the column after the active filtering scheme and markings are applied.

However, this output column is only calculated if I have something marked in every marking.

I want the output column to be calculated no matter how many of the markings are being used. Is there a way to do this?

I was thinking I could use an IronPython script to edit the data function parameters for my input column to only check the boxes for markings that are actively being used. However, I can't find how to access those parameters with IronPython.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a combination of visuals being set to OR instead of AND for markings (if you have a set of markings that are being set from others).

Also are all the input parameters set to required parameter perhaps unchecking that option would still run the script. In the r script you may want to replace null values as well.

Not too sure without some example.

Comment: I unchecked the require parameters option, and it worked well, thanks!